# Add Maven build number to JS sources in html page during building process

Tags: java, html, maven

I have a Maven project and my aim is to find a way how to append a build number during each build to JS source files in existing html file. I expect to obtain after build.

```
<script src="JSsource.js?ver=123123"></script>
```

I have tried to deal with it via maven-war-plugin, ${build.number} and buildnumber-maven-plugin, but unsuccessfully - my file still has a name with a variable name.

```
<script src="JSsource.js?ver=${buildNumber}"></script>
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? Resources are copied, but with placeholder, not value? Or resources are not copied? Also, documentation suggests to try `**/*.html` if your files are not directly in `webapp`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that variables are not set into a proper place and I have a ${build.number} in my html. I should have mentioned it - excuse me.

Comment: You can use `${project.version}` for the maven version number. Or you'll need to pass in a build number as a system property (eg CI revision number) and reference it using `${some.system.property}` (eg `mvn -Dsome.system.property=12345 clean install`

Comment: you should probably enable resources filtering then, as per official documentation, [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Comment: Lance Java Thanks for idea, but adding ${project.version} didn't work as well. Even ${pom.version} fails to work properly. In terms of manual system property - I'd like to make this process completely automatical, thus, suppose, it isn't a good way out.

Comment: You can also try defining an [overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) with filtering. Anyhow, please also post your pom.xml - perhaps there are some non-obvious things missing or misconfigured.